# Which MySQL DB engine (MyISAM vs InnoDB) for very busy tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have doubts about which DB engine choose to few of my tables. I've already studied several articles, books and similar databases construction, but still not sure.

**Website characteristics** - place for young music producers to share their work(music) with others. As you my guess, there will be a lot of queries when uploading and downloading music.

Here are two main tables in my DB: **'Users'** - 27 Columns and **'Files'** - 22 Columns

Here is my question which engine will be better MyISAM vs InnoDB for both tables ?

MyISAM lock whole table so if I understand correctly when somebody uploading files MySQL locks table to write file data and then if in the same time somebody requesting to download even other file this request have to wait until Mysql unlock table right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you yourself said that MyISAM tables use table-level locking. So if the traffic is high InnoDB will be the right choice. With MyISAM, only one user can interact at a time. You have to make sure that your hardware can keep up with these traffic to avoid being overrun.

That suggests to me you would need a storage engine which supports row-level locking, i.e., InnoDB.

Comment: Thanks, I have additional question, I have one column with data type tinyint(3) ,  for test I updated this columnt to value 200 and for my surprise it shows this value. So my question is why and how display width works if after arrange that I only need values from 0 -3 I can see bigger ones.

Comment: Thank you, also is there a difference in database size when I use tinyint(1) instead of tinyint(3) in case of millions rows ?

Comment: Let me clarify it. In tinyint(m) m indicates the column width in SELECT statements; however, it doesn't control the accepted range of numbers for that field. TinyINT(M) always has a range from -128..+127. It doesn't matter what the size of M is. And Yes, tinyint(1) and tinyint(3)  doesn't make any difference in database size :)

Comment: Thank, two more questions about speed comparsion between MyISAM and InnoDB and locking. Just to clarify, when somebody updating / inserting something to table, table is locked and other users can't write and read from table until lock is disabled right ?

When autocommit is set to 1 what is equal to ON, InnoDB doesn't use transaction schema and works like MyISAM unles I use state "start transaction" ?

Also how looks InnoDB read speed in comparsion to MyISAM ?